# Webdriver crashes when using it with Selenium. How to resolve it?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2GBO_QjRlo) online resource, for building an Instagram bot. In it, the instructor uses selenium, which I installed by running: `pip3 install selenium`

Then he mentioned using [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/). I downloaded it and installed it following this [resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz59GsdvUF8). I tested it and seemingly it worked, however when I tried to use it in my script it crashed, an error message occured: `Error sending sync broker message: the pipe is being closed (0xE8)`

The script which I ran when the error occurred is:

```
from selenium import webdriver


class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('https://instagram.com')


InstaBot()
```

How my I resolve this error? I read through dozens of articles, but still not found what causes. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and it works fine for me.
Try to update your chrome browser to the latest version (79.0.3945.130) and download its match ChromeDriver version (79.0.3945.36).
Note that the ChromeDriver should be on the same folder with your code.